# Using Cython with Django. Does it make sense?

Tags: python, django, cython

Is it possible to optimize speed of a mission critical application developed in Django with Cython?

Recently I have read on the internet, that Cython can turn a Python code to C like speed. Is this possible with Django?

Comment: Instragram use Django and have been optimising parts of their codebase using Cython: youtube.com/watch?v=_1MSX7V28Po

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is it possible to optimize speed of a mission critical application developed in Django with Cython

It's doubtful.

Most of a web application response time is the non-HTML elements that must be downloaded separately.  The usual rule of thumb is 8 static files per HTML page.  (.CSS, .JS, images, etc.)

Since none of that static content comes from Django, most of your web application's time-line is Apache (or Nginx or some other server software outside Django).

When looking at just the time to produce the HTML, you'll find that most of the time is spent waiting for the database (even if it's in-memory SQLite, you'll see that the database tends to dominate the timeline)

When you're through making Apache and the database go fast, then -- and only then -- you can consider the Python elements.

Bottom Line.  Don't waste any of your time on making Django and Python go faster.

Comment: This would be correct in most of scenarios, around 95% where the django based application is mostly CRUD. But if the web-application engine needs to do a lot of computations, and not just fetching data, applying filter and return. In that case, python becomes the bottleneck, and there one would either think of optimizing this codebase or move to better (but tougher) alternatives.

Comment: Couldn't it be used to optimize a Django API though since you don't have to serve CSS, JS, etc.?

Comment: This is misleading and incorrect, especially if you aren't serving assets (which Python shouldn't do in a production app). I'd ballpack that 95% of the time of a request is spent in Python, the rest in nginx and routing.

Comment: As @DanielvanFlymen said, aren't static assets usually added as links, and then the browser downloads them from a the static URL, that could be served by NGINX/Apache/etc on the same server, or another (CDN)? Meaning Python does NOT matter for static assets, but just how fast the view is rendered after receiving the queryset data. Faster queryset data processing and faster view rendering = faster response time...

Answer (score 25):

Well, yes, but most things a web app does won't really benefit from this sort of change unless you have firm proof that it will. Profile twice, optimize once.

Answer (score 12):

Conceptually what you are after is possible, but you are looking in the wrong direction.

You really should be interested in PyPy, which is an extremely promising technology for the Django (and Python) community. Benchmarks of Django on PyPy already show a **12.5X speed gain** when compared to normal Python. Now even though front end static resources may contribute to the majority of page responsiveness to the end user (per S.Lott's answer above), this does not address the reality that speed gains on the server side are extremely important. Facebook had to invent HipHop PHP for this reason...the lag of PHP just couldn't cut it. Closer to home, simply consider that Meebo (a python driven site) spends tens of thousands USD per month on server infrastructure. Now can you taste the server cost savings with PyPy? Sexy!

Check out the benchmarks: http://speed.pypy.org/

Comment: PyPy  requires lots of memory which keeps on increasing. Right now one of our application starts from 1.5GB of Ram and within a day reaches 3.1 GB

Comment: Please report your use case to the PyPy devs if you can't locate the source of the leak. (Please ensure your app itself or misuse of c-based libraries like NumPy are not the cause and that it doesn't occur in the CPython version of Django.)

Comment: Doesn't pypy slow bd access?

Answer (score 5):

Echoing the other answers, this is unlikely to gain you any specific gains, unless of course, you've profiled a specific case where some benefit could be derived.

Adding to the answers, I want to point out a list of web optimizations from the Yahoo's web  team.  These are measured and proven gains in areas applicable to many websites and worth studying:

- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

> The Exceptional Performance team has identified a number of best practices for making web pages fast. The list includes 35 best practices divided into 7 categories.

Answer (score 4):

We have built an application that is installed on the customer site called [InProd](http://www.inprod.io), it manages the configuration of Genesys powered contact centers. It is a Django application compiled with Cython.

There is a speed improvement but it is not considerable. We need to process a lot of requests per second and the main delay in doing this is caused by the database.  The biggest gains are to be made with database tuning and good sql.

You need to have a really strong need to do such a thing as it does cause on going issues, it increases our testing requirements.

The performance difference can be large on some tasks, but not all. So the improvement will depend on what your application is doing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have heavy processes on the backend side. In my case it could improve one of the processes and speed it up ~5 times. I had a function that rework large XML files that is inputed by the user and save the output into database. telling Cython that in some places the input or output is string did the 5x speed up magic.